# About involution

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Below is an excerpt from chapter 7 of Winfried Scharlau's [*Quadratic and Hermitian Forms*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-69971-9_7):

[image]

[image]

I understand that how to convert left module to right module by involution.But what is meaning of we always interpret dual module M* as right module in this sense? Also what is meaning of scalar multiplication is twisted by involution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we work over a commutative ring $R$ and $M$ is a **left** $R$-module, the dual module $M^*$ is considered to be Hom$(M,R)$ with **right** $R$-module structure.

If we now take $R$ to be not necessarily commutative, then $M^*=$Hom$(M,R)$ has, a priori, only a **left** $R$-module structure, given by $(\alpha f)x=\alpha(fx)$ for $f\in M^*$, $x\in M$, $\alpha\in R$. We'd want to put a **right** $R$-module structure on $M^*$, and we can do when $R$ has an involution $*$, for then we can "twist" the left action to a right one, with the cost of changing the scalar to its conjugate via the involution: we define $$f\cdot\alpha:=\alpha^* f,$$
so that $(f\alpha)(x)=\alpha^*(fx)$ for $f\in M^*$, $x\in M$, $\alpha\in R$.

Now suppose that $R$ is commutative with a nontrivial involution and $M$ is a left $R$-module. We have two ways of taking the dual of $M$: one is by considering the natural right action of $R$ on $M$, which would give $f\alpha=\alpha f$; the other is by considering the right action coming from twisting the left action via the involution, which would give $f\alpha=\alpha^* f$. You can see that they are different (e.g. if $R=\mathbb{C}$ and $\alpha=i$ then the second action has a negative sign with respect to the first). So we have to be careful in this case, because we could be giving the same name to two different objects.

---

**Edited to address further questions**

1) We have $(M\oplus N)^*=M^*\oplus N^*$: by definition, if $f\in(M\oplus N)^*$ then $f:M\oplus N\rightarrow R$. Consider the projections $f_M:M\rightarrow R$, $f_N:N\rightarrow R$ such that $f(m+n)=f_M(m)+f_N(n)$ for $m\in M, n\in N$, and the right $R$-module structures are compatible. This shows that $(M\oplus N)^*\subseteq M^*\oplus N^*$. Conversely, if $f_M\in M^*$ and $f_N\in N^*$  then $f:=f_M+f_N\in (M\oplus N)^*$ and all operations go well, so the two modules are the same.

2) Let us see that $R\cong R^*$ as right modules: We suppose that $R$ has identity. If the action was not twisted, we could use the *regular representation* $\phi:R\rightarrow$Hom$(R,R)$, $\phi(r)=\phi_r$ such that $\phi_r(x):=xr$, but due to the twisting caused by the involution we are going to consider $\phi_r(x):=r^*x$.

First we see that $\phi$ is a homomorphism of right $R$-modules. If $r,s\in R$ then $\phi_{r+s}(x)=(r+s)^*x=(r^*+s^*)x=r^*x+s^*x=\phi_r(x)+\phi_s(x)$ for all $x\in R$ implies that $\phi(r+s)=\phi(r)+\phi(s)$, and $\phi_{sr}(x)=(sr)^*(x)=(r^*s^*)x=r^*(s^*x)=r^*\phi_s(x)=\phi_s(x)\cdot r$ implies that $\phi(sr)=\phi(s)\cdot r$.

Now wee see that $\phi$ is injective: since it is additive it is enough tho show that $\phi(r)=0$ implies $r=0$. This is true because $\phi_r(x)=0$ for all $x$ implies $r^*x=0$ for all $x$, in particular $r^*=r^*1=0$, hence $r=0$.

Finally, we show that $\phi$ is surjective: Given $f\in$Hom$(R,R)$ note that $f(x)=f(1x)=f(1)x$, so $f$ is determined by $f(1)$; hence $\phi(f(1)^*)=f$ since $\phi_{f(1)^*}(x)=(f(1)^*)^*x=f(1)x=f(x)$ for all $x\in R$.

Comment: @ninjahatori Please, see the update in my answer.

Comment: @ninjahatori OK, let's see if I can help you!